# In Microsoft BI how do you model a fact table when user selecting data between two times

Tags: data-modeling, business-intelligence, dax, tabular

I have a modelling issue regarding selecting all data for a duration (between a start and end time).
I will probably end up using Tabular/PowerPivot for this but it could also be PowerBI or excel querying the database directly.

**Summary:**
I have a fact table (Fact_Session) with a StartDateTime & EndDateTime column. Users need to see data between a start and end Time.
There is a second fact table (fact_Products)  that lists Products scanned by a user with a specific device and the time it was scanned at.

**Requirement:**
When a user selects a start & end time they need to see:

- All sessions between that start and end time, in Fact_Session.
- All products scanned between start and end time, in Fact_Products

This will most likely mean two pivot tables with thier data linked via the dimensions, in particular the Time dimension.

**Issues/Questions:**

- Do I need two time dimensions, one for startTime and one for EndTime?
- How do I tie the period between start and end time to the FactProducts table?

Appreciate any help and advice on this.

Image of semi complete (without time dimension) logical diagram is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need two separate date/time dimensions. The references need to be independent. Check out this information from the [Kimball Group](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/role-playing-dimension/)

Not sure how familiar you are with dimensional modelling, though you don't need to create a completely separate table in the database, a view would suffice as this allows for an independent reference.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helps, but doesnt answer the main question, which is if i have a start and end time dimension, how do i select all rows from 2nd fact table that falls within that date range. Note from the diagram that the 2nd fact table(fact_products) just has a "Time_Scanned" column that stores the time/date the scan took place, its not however a range.

Comment: I see. Querying the database directly you would want conditional logic such as where (fact_session.Start_Date)Time >= selectedstarttime and fact_session.EndDateTime <= selectedendtime) or (fact_product.time_scanned >= selectedstarttime and fact_product.time_scanned <= selectedendtime)

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirement to display all products and all sessions limits the options. If you didn't need to display the detail you could use disconnected date table(s), one or two of them, and then produce measures along the lines of (in the case of one date table):

```
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [ProductIDCount] ),
    FILTER ( Fact_Products, Fact_Products[Time_Scanned] > MIN ( Calendar[Date] ) ),
    FILTER ( Fact_Products, Fact_Products[Time_Scanned] < MAX ( Calendar[Date] ) )
)
```

where MIN(Calendar[Date]) will be the lowest date selected and MAX the highest. But this won't work for the row level detail from Fact_Products. It will only work for measures.

If you are delivering via Excel you could change the approach by having users select dates from a timeline which automatically provide a range. Once you have a range you can have a connected date table which will give you the details you need. hth

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, as i needed to show a list of tasks based on the selected date, I am using something like this

```
Active = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(task), 
    FILTER(task, ([Start] <= LASTDATE(Mstdate[Date]) 
        && [finish]>= FIRSTDATE(Mstdate[Date]))))
```

the date table should not be linked to the fact table, then i use active >0 as a filter in your pivot

you can download the model here https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYjkwZTMyY2EtYTE1Ny00OWQzLWJlZDktNjkxN2JkOTA3ZmIxIiwidCI6ImI2ZWM3ZGYwLTc1ZGEtNDc2Ni04MGI0LWNlYzM1MzZlNGYzYSIsImMiOjEwfQ%3D%3D